# Explicitly specializing template, static vs. duplicate symbols

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, template-specialization, boost-test

In a bunch of legacy code I have inherited, unit tests are implemented using [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/). To enable checking `std::wstring` and [`icu::UnicodeString`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/) for equality via `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL()`, the original author implemented explicit template specializations for `equal_impl()`:

```
// test_utils.hpp

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>

namespace boost
{
namespace test_tools
{
namespace tt_detail
{

template<>
static
boost::test_tools::predicate_result equal_impl( const std::wstring & wleft, const icu::UnicodeString & uright )
{
    const icu::UnicodeString uleft = w2u( wleft );
    return uleft == uright;
}

template<>
static
boost::test_tools::predicate_result equal_impl( const icu::UnicodeString & uleft, std::wstring & wright )
{
    const icu::UnicodeString uright = w2u( wright );
    return uleft == uright;
}

}
}
}
```

Now, this construct labels the template specializations as `static`. I understand that old GCC versions accepted this, but today's versions (post-4.3-ish) reject it:

```
error: explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class
```

However, if I *remove* the `static`, I get `multiple definition` at link time. And I can't put everything in an anonymous namespace, can I, since I have to specialize the template in `boost::test_tools::tt_detail`?

I am at a loss on how to resolve this (short of a complete refactoring of all the tests to using [a custom predicate](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/custom-predicate.html) instead of `BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL()`)...?

Note that C++11 is, unfortunately, not an option at this point, as not all target platforms have appropriate compiler support yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `static` with `inline` and it'll be ok.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a medal. (Somehow, for all these long years, I could never hammer it into my head that `inline` can be used to indicate linking scope as well as optimization hint...)